# Can NaN class be assigned to a certain class in imbalanced datasets (binary classification)?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, binary-data, unbalanced-classes

I'm working on a spam detection binary classification problem, but the dataset is very imbalanced (99% to 1%). I know there are techniques like over/under sampling, but I don't think it can be used in this scenario due to the extremely low raw number of positive class samples.

However, a large number of the samples in the dataset have a "NaN" class. I was wondering if it is sensible to assign these classes as belonging to the positive class, or if this is something you should never do in a binary classification problem (in case it's considered as "cheating").

I'm planning on using common algorithms such as logistic regression, KNN, SVM, etc. Perhaps instead of reassigning NaN samples, there is another way of modelling which is better suited to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that they’re really part of the class to which you’d be assigning them?

Comment: Why are they NaN?

Comment: @Dave I don't have reason to believe it - I tried clustering and PCA to see if there was any relationships, but the samples are all over the place irrespective of the class label.

Comment: @Tim The dataset was just provided in this manner (positive, negative, NaN).

Comment: You say "positive, negative", but are these really just `+1` or `-1` or gradual? Perhaps you should in fact tackle this as a regression problem, not as a classification one at all?

Answer (score 5):

You could treat the NaNs as unlabelled data and use a [semi-supervised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning) learning algorithm, but as @Tim (+1) suggests, labelling them as positive is likely to bias the results.  Unless you know the mechanism generating the NaNs, the best you can do is likely to be to ignore the labels entirely and just use the attribute vector.  There are semi-supervised versions of logistic regression and the SVM.

Note that imbalance generally is not an inherent problem.  If ignoring the minority class is unacceptable, it probably means your application has unequal misclassification costs, and you just need to take them into account (e.g. for the SVM by having different slack penalties for positive and negative patterns).  But considering misclassification costs is something we should be doing anyway, and the imbalance does not affect the solution to the cost-sensitive learning problem.

Just a thought, as it is a spam dataset, it could be that the negative examples are emails that were caught by the spam filter, but labelled by the user as ham, and the positive examples could be labelled as spam by the user.  The NaN ones may be emails that were caught by a spam filter, but were not checked by the user?

Comment: The problem I'm having with training with common classification algorithms is that the model just predicts everything as being negative, so it's a pretty useless model and I have no way of actually understanding if the model is good or not. In situations like this are you just supposed to accept the fact that your model could be bad?

Comment: @fx-85 It depends, if false-negative errors are equally bad as false-positive errors, then from a classification perspective, that is the optimal solution.  However for things like spam, classifying ham as spam is probably worse than classifying spam as ham, so if you take that into account in your training criterion, it may be possible to have a meaningful classification.  It is probably best to use a probabilistic classifier, such as kernel logistic regression, as then you can experiment with misclassification costs without having to re-fit the model.

Comment: I tend to use KLR more often than SVM these days, if the dataset isn't too large it is a very good model, and tuning the hyper-parameters reliably is easier.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that. If you are missing the labels, you don't know them, they can be either positive or negative. If you made the labels positive you are possibly adding incorrect labels to the data, so adding noise to it, biasing your results.

Comment: Would it be viable if I was to draw a decision boundary around the negative class and then check whether the NaN samples fit within this decision boundary (thus labelling them as negative, else positive)? Or is it just a bad idea to infer class labels in general?

Comment: @fx-85 what for?

Comment: Otherwise my model will just predict everything as being negative as it barely has any positive samples to learn from.

Comment: @fx-85 if most of your labels are negative it seems to be reasonable result. Changing NaN’s to positive labels is as arbitrary as a solution as changing negative labels to positive.